# Two of the same subnets on the same network. Possible?

Tags: networking, router, subnet

I have a question for everyone that I am a little confused about.

If you have a network. 192.168.1.254. I know you can put in a router as a gateway and get another network with 192.168.10.254. My question is can you do TWO of those routers

```
                [Router]{192.168.10.254}              
192.168.1.254--{        
                [Router]{192.168.10.254}
```

Or will this create cross talk? Each router has it's own IP on the first network and they are technically separated but I just have a feeling it won't work.

I hope I explained correctly. Please ask if you want more info.

Comment: You need to provide more information. Who will talk with who. What routing protocols are you using etc. Theoretically you could even use 1 router and have two different networks with the same subnet using VRF https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_routing_and_forwarding but again it all depends on what you need to accomplish to get a proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cannot comment :(

no, sorry that is not possible. But you can "cut" the main network into two halfs.

e.g. 192.168.10.1-192.168.10.127 and 192.168.10.128-192.168.10.254

so it will be 192.168.10.1 and 192.168.10.128 for the two routers

Maybe tell us a littlebit more, I will then update this answer

Comment: Thank you for the answer. No, that really won't work. I need the gateway to be the same on both networks but not talk to each other. But that is very useful if I ever need to do that.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't.

In router 192.168.1.254 it need a route back to talk to 192.168.10.X, you can't have two route to the same network.

As the router 192.168.10.254 will have an IP in the WAN (aka 192.168.1.X), thus two distinct IP there for the two router.

*The only trick you can do, is to make a lower subnet on 192.168.1.254's side. (/25) For 1. .128 it talk to router #1, For 129. .254 it talk to router #2. Keep in mind the IP on 192.168.10.X's side, even if in a /24, will be isolated if not in the correct's range for the router in question, as they will never get the answer back. This trick is not a bestpractice at all, as it's confusing for anyone that will try to diag your network.*

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I appreciate you taking the time to let me know but this won't work for my application.