# Can two LAN networks both at one level behind a router higher up the routing chain use the same subnet mask and network ID?

Tags: routing, nat, subnet, tcpip

Can two LAN networks both at one level behind a router higher up the routing chain use the same subnet mask and network ID? See the diagram below.

This question was already answered [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/705634/two-of-the-same-subnets-on-the-same-network-possible), but I am wondering why not if so.

Seeing as the two subnets are isolated from each other and each router has a different external IP from the upstream router, it seems there is no possibility of IP overlap interfering with the routing.

Am I wrong? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Don't. Implement IPv6 and have enough address space for globally unique addressing.   NAT alone does not isolate duplicate IPs, if a host does address resolution and gets two answers, what then?

Comment: Aren't ARP broadcasts limited to the LAN?

Comment: You have not indicated how the layer 2 is isolated, not even a VLAN. Your routers have the same IP address, so many simple NAT implementations will not work.  Implement IPv6 if you can, and renumber the IPv4 networks to be unique if you must.

Answer (score -1):

Not this way, you could do 192.168.1.* and 10.0.1.* for example. You might need to seperate modem and router for that and use a professional grade router for that, or something like opnsense on. Raspberry pi

Comment: I'm wondering what doesn't work with the way mentioned though. It seems the two internal lans are hidden behind a layer of NAT and the upper level network shouldn't care.